# Is there a way to unlock features right off the bat?

Tags: cities-skylines

In Cities: Skylines, some features are locked by default, like the fire department, dense zoning, and districts. You need to reach a certain population to unlock them. Is there a way to unlock these from the start?

Comment: There is a mod available by default that you can enable. I'll flesh this out in a bit.

Comment: The game kinda holds your hand to start. You unlock more buildings and zones as you gain population. On top of that, there's unique buildings that each have their own requirements to unlock. I don't think the question is vague enough to warrant closing.

Comment: There are quite a lot of mods available which unlock various features from the start. Is that what you are asking about?

Answer (score 5):

Cities: Skylines ships with three "mods" in the game.

They are:

- Hard Mode - More challenge for experienced players
- Unlimited Money - Money never runs out
- Unlock All - Progression milestones are always unlocked

You want the third one. To enable this mod, from the main menu, go to *Content Manager*. In the left panel select the *Mods* category. Then, click the *On/Off* checkbox under *Unlock All*.

It should look like this:

[image: The Mods menu in Cities: Skylines, with Unlock All selected.]